# Group isomorphism construction

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm having a hard time with the following question:

Let $S^1=\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x>0\}$.

Show that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}\cong S^1 \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

I was trying to use Isomorphism theorems, but it didn't work out.

Can I have a subtle hint here? Do I need to construct an isomorphism, or is there a theorem that solves it all?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: think about polar coordinates

Comment: $x=z \to (\frac z {|z|},|z|)$.

Comment: Thank you! @KaviRamaMurthy